In vacuum decay, why must the bounce solution be a stationary point, but not necessarily a minimum of the Euclidean action?
In Chapter 12 of Weinberg's Classical solutions in QFT the author discusses vacuum decay and in particular the thin wall approximation. Eq.12.32 describes the action of the solution as a function of the bounce radius: $$ S[R] = 2 \pi^2 R^3 \sigma - \frac{1}{2} \pi^2 R^4 \epsilon$$
By taking the derivative $\frac{dS}{dR}=0$, the bounce radius is given as $R_b = \frac{3 \sigma}{\epsilon}$. This made sense initially to me as consistent with Hamilton's Principle of Least Action, the most likely path should minimise the action. Taking the 2nd derivative however it is clear $R_b$ maximises, rather than minimises the action. The author states this explicitly: " [$R_b$] maximizes the action among the family of configurations". If this radius maximises action then I don't follow why the false vacuum would ever decay in this way. I fear this comes from a misunderstanding of what Euclidean action represents here.
